# How to connect .mpp file stored in a sharepoint library to PowerBI. no server or PWA available

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, project

any suggestion on how to connect .mpp file stored in a sharepoint library to PowerBI. no server or PWA is available.

Comment: No, Power BI cannot just read Microsoft Project files. There must be some Microsoft Project software, who reads the file and exposes an API, etc.